# htaccess how to exclude css js files

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a syntax in htaccess:

```
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/([a-z0-9-_.]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?n=$2&z=$3&t=$4 [L,QSA]`
```

result:

```
www.someweb.com/file1/n1/s1/t2
www.someweb.com/file2/n2/s2/t2
etc.
```

But all of my css, js files not found. all of them have directory starts from css/file.css, js/file.js, img/file.jpg etc. When i execute index.php, all of css, js are visible,

When i put "/" to the every directory in php file, that files are not visible for index.php and visible for example: www.someweb.com/file2/n2/s2/t2

How can i write this syntax in htaccess to visibility css, js files both of above examples - index.php and for example: www.someweb.com/file2/n2/s2/t2.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: hmm. It works! I spent 5 hours looking for a solution!!!. I did't think the solution would be that easy!!! Great Thanks!!!